Google auth with react native app crashes
I am trying to build authentication flow using '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin'
I used eac for building my app and run it with expo development. once I am clicking on my login my app crashed with the following error:
 Your app just crashed. See the error below.
NSInvalidArgumentException: Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: <schema that I took from google developer>
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae138 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180087db4 objc_exception_throw + 56
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae048 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
  3   Drafts                              0x0000000102c9cb90 -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 444
  4   Drafts                              0x0000000102c9ba90 -[GIDSignIn signInWithPresentingViewController:hint:additionalScopes:completion:] + 208
  5   Drafts                              0x0000000102d27468 __43-[RNGoogleSignin signIn:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 372
  6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000180170104 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
  7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000180171978 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001801807c8 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1276
  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001801802bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
  10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018040e9a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
  11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804090b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
  12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180408514 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
  13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018ef06ae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
  14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001853e8040 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
  15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001853ebcc8 UIApplicationMain + 124
  16  Drafts                              0x0000000102acb7a0 main + 96
  17  dyld                                0x0000000105d19544 start_sim + 20
  18  ???                                 0x00000001056ae0e0 0x0 + 4385857760
  19  ???                                 0xda6d000000000000 0x0 + 15739236272729751552

I added to my app.js file under ios this fields:
"infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
          {
            "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
              <schema from google developer for IOS>
            ]
          }
        ]
      }

and inside the component:
import {
    GoogleSignin,
    GoogleSigninButton,
    statusCodes,
  } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';


const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const {login,} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)

    const configureGoogleSignIn = () => { GoogleSignin.configure({
        iosClientId:<clientId from google developer that the schema matches to my app.js>,
    })
}

    useEffect(() => {
        configureGoogleSignIn();
    });

    const signIn = async () => {
       const userName =  await GoogleSignin.signIn()
    }
    
    return (
        <View>
            <GoogleSigninButton onPress = {signIn}/>
        </View>
    )
};

